# Extremely slow SQL query - XML Path function

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a last ditch effort to see if anyone has some pointers on how I can increase the execution speed of this SQL query. The XML map path really slows this query down. It takes over 21 seconds to execute:

```
 SELECT [ldid],
       l.loadnumber,
       l.expectdt,
       l.receivedt,
       l.actualarrvdt,
       l.carrcode,
       c.carrdesc,
       cpl.refnum AS PONum,
       c.phone,
       l.source,
       l.pallets,
       l.comment,
       l.drivercell,
       [loadtrackingstatusid],
       Stuff((SELECT *
              FROM   (SELECT ','
                             + Cast(Cast(cpl.qty AS INT) AS VARCHAR)
                             + ' ' + Ltrim(Rtrim(p.proddesc)) + ' '
                             + Ltrim(Rtrim(p.prodpack) ) AS x
                      FROM   custpoline cpl
                             JOIN product p
                               ON p.prodid = cpl.prodid
                      WHERE  ( ( cpl.loadnumber = l.loadnumber )
                               AND l.source = 'LD' )
                              OR ( ( cpl.refnum = l.loadnumber )
                                   AND l.source = 'PO' )
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT ',' + Cast(Cast(i.qty AS INT) AS VARCHAR)
                             + ' ' + Ltrim(Rtrim(p.proddesc)) + ' '
                             + Ltrim(Rtrim(p.prodpack))
                      FROM   inventory i
                             JOIN product p
                               ON p.prodid = i.prodid
                      WHERE  ( i.referencenum = l.loadnumber )
                             AND l.source = 'IX') a
              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS
       proddesc
FROM   [Sales].[dbo].[load] l
LEFT JOIN carrier c ON c.carrcode = l.carrcode
LEFT JOIN custpoline cpl ON cpl.loadnumber = l.loadnumber
WHERE  startdt IS NULL
       AND enddt IS NULL
       AND expectdt >= Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate())
       AND expectdt <= Dateadd(day, 1, Getdate())
       AND cpl.warehouse = 'GU'
ORDER  BY expectdt DESC
```

I tried removing the `ltrim` and `rtrim` functions. And I tried different cast data types. I'm hoping someone has some ideas.

Thanks folks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, however, can `i.qty` and `cpl.qty` only have a value between 0 and 9? Your code implies this.

Comment: Can you attach a query plan? Also what sort of rowcounts are you serializing there? (both outer and inner)?

Comment: @Larnu i.qty & cpl.qty could have a max int value potentially.

Comment: I'd wonder if the stuff subselect line could be turned into it's own query and joined back...subqueries like that have the bad tendancy to force the query planner to loop itself.

Comment: Then declare your `varchar` length. :)

Comment: @Larnu wow - that shaves off several seconds. Interesting. That's great.

Comment: @Twelfth how would you suggest I implement something like that?